# How to use std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

When I use `std::thread` like this:

```
func()
{
   std::thread(std::bind(&foo, this));
}
```

the thread object is allocated in stack and is destroyed when `func()` returns.
So I try to use it like:

```
func()
{
   std::thread* threadPtr = new std::thread(std::bind(&foo, this));
}
```

Where should I `delete threadPtr`?
And how can I create a thread that is initially suspended?

Comment: "Where should I delete threadPtr? " That's up to you, but you don't have a handle to delete it with anywhere except inside the function.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? We might be able to give you better advice if you tell us the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the thread to run independently, you need to use the `detach()` method on the object. Otherwise, the `thread` destructor will terminate your program if the object is destroyed while the thread is still running.

Threads start running as soon as they are created. You cannot create a thread object in a suspended state. You can either store the arguments to create the thread instead of actually creating it (possibly using, for instance, `std::function`), or make it block on a mutex or a condition variable until you are ready to let it run.

Comment: so the code should be `auto threadObj = std::thread(std::bind(&foo, this)); threadObj.Detach()`?

Comment: @Zach Depending on what your thread is doing `detach` may not be appropriate (e.g., if it accesses resources of an object that is destroyed while the thread is still executing).

Comment: @Zach They are referring to [`std::thread::detach`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach).

Comment: @James Adkison, thanks. `detach()` is what I wanted.

Answer (score 6):

> How to use std::thread?

It depends on what you're doing in the thread, but most likely you'll want to use `join`. It is also possible to use `detach` but care must be taken to make sure it doesn't use any resources that may be destroyed while its executing.

> std::thread(std::bind(&foo, this));

This doesn't make any sense. You're binding (using `bind` is not necessary) a `this` pointer but `&foo` is not a pointer to a member function (which would look like `&Foo::foo`). Assuming you meant to use a pointer to a member function that would mean `func` is also a member function of the same class (i.e., since it has access to the `this` pointer) therefore the following code gives you an example of something you *could do*.

### Example Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() = default;

    ~Foo()
    {
        if (mThread.joinable())
        {
            mThread.join();
        }
    }

    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo::foo\n";
    }

    void func()
    {
        if (mThread.joinable())
        {
            mThread.join();
        }

        // Creates the thread without using 'std::bind'
        mThread = std::thread(&Foo::foo, this);
    }

private:
    std::thread mThread;
};

int main()
{
    {
        Foo f;
        f.func();
        f.func();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Example Output

```
Foo::foo
Foo::foo
```

> Where should I delete threadPtr?

I wouldn't dynamically allocate the thread, but in the above example code you would delete it after joining.

> how can I create a thread that is initially suspended?

C++ doesn't directly support this but you can use platform specific APIs with `std::thread::native_handle`. **Note**, if you wanted to block just once at the very start you could possibly achieve this with a synchronization primitive (e.g., block on a `std::mutex` before running the actual thread).